# Looking for a converter of AMPL/GAMS models into C code

Tags: c++, c, libraries

I've done an extensive web search, but could not find an option. Conversion between model formats is available, but conversion of objective function and constraint equations into C code seems absent. This is needed to run complex models a little bit more effectively utilizing processor-specific compiler optimizations.

Comment: AMPL and GAMS are modeling languages, used simply to describe your problem. They then call some other solver on the backend to actually solve the problem. The solvers themselves are compiled binaries (and can thus take advantage of processor-specific compiler optimizations), so on the surface, it doesn't seem to make much sense to translate AMPL/GAMS to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution which converts NL format to C program. NL format can be obtained from AMPL input easily.
https://ampl.com/netlib/ampl/solvers/nlc/index.html